# Google Colab: mounted Drive but unable to read files

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am doing Stanford's course CS231n on deep learning and am using Google Colab.
The initialization code and all the files are given, so all i need is just to hit "run" on the given code.

**I have followed step be step the official instructions and successfully mounted Google Drive**, yet i get an error when trying to read the files:
**"cp: cannot stat 'cs231n/assignments/assignment1/cs231n/': No such file or directory /content".**
And then some more errors.

The files are located in my drive as in the path "FOLDERNAME".

The errors i get:

[image: my error]

How it should be:

[image: correct]

Official instructions:
https://cs231n.github.io/assignments2020/assignment1/

How can i solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am having the exactly same problem as you were. And here is my solution:

1. delete the folder named cs231n
2. follow the tutorial again

**3. change the path `%cd drive/My\ Drive` into `%cd drive/MyDrive`**

[image]

As you can see, default setting of the folder is 'MyDrive'(without space in midddle) but not 'My Drive'(My\ Drive).

[image]

Then, everything should run as your expectation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the course instructions, it sounds like you need to expand the course archive in your Drive.

Quoting here:

> Create a folder in your personal Google Drive and upload assignment1/
> folder to the Drive folder. We recommend that you call the Google
> Drive folder cs231n/assignments/ so that the final uploaded folder has
> the path cs231n/assignments/assignment1/.

If you already did that, I'd check the Drive web UI to make sure that the paths line up with the course instructions, and to move the files around if there's a mismatch.